# How to do a recursive function for a tree view?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, tree, iteration, reduce

How do I use the following data properties to render a tree view using nested unordered lists(`<ul>`)?

```
// parentId value is always 0 for root nodes, otherwise this value corresponds to the id of its parent
// sequence represents the order of the element in the branch
// level represents the tree level of the element, root nodes will have a level of 1
var data = [
  { id: 'K66', level: 1, name: 'B', parentId: '0', sequence: 2 },
  { id: 'K65', level: 1, name: 'A', parentId: '0', sequence: 1 },
  { id: 'KK2', level: 2, name: 'Alan', parentId: 'K65', sequence: 1 },
  { id: 'KK22', level: 2, name: 'Bir', parentId: 'K66', sequence: 1 },
  { id: 'KK92', level: 2, name: 'Abe', parentId: 'K65', sequence: 2 },
  { id: 'KK77', level: 3, name: 'Boromir', parentId: 'KK22', sequence: 1 }
];
```

The result should look like the following:

```
A
  Alan
  Abe
B
  Bir
    Boromir
```

I have tried with for loops but soon I was repeating code to get the child nodes and I wasn't able to refactor it into a recursive function.

Here's a CodePen with the data: http://codepen.io/nunoarruda/pen/KgVPmv

Comment: Have you yet searched "Javascript render tree" on SO?  There are some existing solutions.  You haven't posted your coding attempt (MCVE), which may affect your response rate.

Comment: @nunoarruda ... a recursive approach is not necessary. Have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer following part of the OP's question ...

> How do I use the following data properties to render a tree view using nested unordered lists()?

With the given data structure there is no need for a recursive solution. A combination of `sort`ing the provided data list and then transforming it via a specific `reduce` callback already does the job ...

```
var
  dataList = [
    { id: 'K66', level: 1, name: 'B', parentId: '0', sequence: 2 },
    { id: 'KK2', level: 2, name: 'Alan', parentId: 'K65', sequence: 1 },
    { id: 'K65', level: 1, name: 'A', parentId: '0', sequence: 1 },
    { id: 'KK77', level: 3, name: 'Boromir', parentId: 'KK22', sequence: 1 },
    { id: 'KK22', level: 2, name: 'Bir', parentId: 'K66', sequence: 1 },
    { id: 'KK92', level: 2, name: 'Abe', parentId: 'K65', sequence: 2 }
  ],

  htmlListFragment = dataList.sort(function (a, b) {

    // sort by `level` or, if both are equal (sub)sort by `sequence`
    return (a.level - b.level) || (a.sequence - b.sequence);

  }).reduce(function (collector, item) {
    var
      registry = collector.registry,
      fragment = collector.htmlListFragment,

      parentId = item.parentId,
      id       = item.id,
      name     = item.name,

      member   = registry[id];

    if (!member) {

      member = registry[id] = document.createElement("li");
      member.id = id;
      member.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
      member.appendChild(document.createElement("ul"));

      if ((item.level === 1) && (item.parentId === "0"))  {

        fragment.appendChild(member);
      } else {
        registry[parentId].getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].appendChild(member);
      }
    }

    return collector;

  }, {

    registry        : {},
    htmlListFragment: document.createElement("ul")

  }).htmlListFragment;


console.log("htmlListFragment : ", htmlListFragment)
```